# Unable to make find.all(string='television') work with BeautifulSoup (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm building a webpage scraper (first time) with the intention to find a specific word in it.

I'm able to get the page and parse it, but when I try to use find.all() or even find() to search for the `string='television'`,

I get 0 results. The word is there. Also, if I try find.all('td') it finds all 2000+ tags, but when I try string I get 0.

Here is the code:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#get site
page_link = 
'https://www.txdot.gov/insdtdot/orgchart/cmd/cserve/bidtab/12033001.htm'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")

match = page_content.find_all(string="television")

print(len(match))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching the text `TELEVISION` which is partial string contains in `td` tag.

So To achieve this.either you can use **regular expression**.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page_link ='https://www.txdot.gov/insdtdot/orgchart/cmd/cserve/bidtab/12033001.htm'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
match = page_content.find_all(text=re.compile("TELEVISION"))
print(len(match))
```

---

Or if you have `beautifulsoup` 4.7.1 or above you can use `css selector` and contains.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_link ='https://www.txdot.gov/insdtdot/orgchart/cmd/cserve/bidtab/12033001.htm'
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
match = page_content.select('td:contains(TELEVISION)')
print(len(match))
```

Please note you have to use exact text which you have on webpage.